# Should I leave my bike on my trainer?

Tags: trainer

I have a cyclops fluid trainer, and for several months each year I only ride on the trainer. Every time I hook the bike up to the trainer, the trainer bends to accommodate the bike. Is it better for the bike and the trainer (overall) to leave the bike on the trainer for several months at a time or take it off the trainer everyday after my workout?

Here is a video of the bike being placed [into the trainer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHvoOnLgsL8): skip to the 1min,20sec mark.

Releasing the pressure between the tire and the roller daily is a no-brainer.

Comment: *it is primarily the trainer I am concerned about.

Answer (score 11):

It will have no negative affect on your bicycle to leave the bike in a trainer for long periods, assuming you have the trainer properly adjusted for the width of your rear axle, and that you do release the roller from the tire as you noted.

In addition, in response to your comment, it will not affect the trainer at all, either.

Answer (score 7):

Shouldn't be a problem to leave the "quick release" of the trainer engaged.  It's ultimately pressing on the ends of the axle, applying pressure the same way the skewer does.  There will be some slight compression of the axle, with added pressure on the bearings as a result, but so long as the pressure isn't extreme (ie, it's on the same order as the pressure from the skewer) then the added bearing pressure will be minimal.

If the added pressure were enough to be a concern you wouldn't even want to ride the bike in the trainer, because the bearings would drag.

Comment: +1 Hadn't even thought about the additional compression effects on the bearings.